# Get data from div class by JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I need to get the value "8.32" from the "rnicper", "36 mg" from "rnstr" and "20/80 PG/VG" from "nirat".

```
<div class="recline highlight" id="rnic">
          <div class="rlab"><span class="nopr indic indic-danger"></span>Nicotine juice <span id="rnstr">36 mg</span> (<span id="nirat">20/80 PG/VG</span>)</div>
          <div class="runit" id="rnicml">2.08</div>
          <div class="rdrops" id="rnicdr">73</div>
          <div class="rgrams" id="rnicg" style="display: none;">2.53</div>
          <div class="rpercent" id="rnicper">8.32</div><br>
        </div>
```

I tried various methods, but nothing happens.

```
doc.getElementById("rnicper").outerHtml();
doc.getElementById("rnicper").text();
doc.select("div#rnicper");
doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "rnicper").text();
```

Tell me, please, how can I get this information using JSOUP?

Update for Chintak Patel

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://e-liquid-recipes.com/recipe/2254223/RY4D%20Vanilla%20Swirl%20DL").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String content =  doc.select("div[id=rnicper]").text();
                Log.d("content", content);

                return null;
            }
        };
        asyncTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

The values of parameters you are trying to get are are not part of initial html, but are set by javascript after page is loaded. 
Jsoup only gets static html, does not execute javascript code.

To get what you want you can use tool like HtmlUnit or Selenium.

HtmlUnit example:

```
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        final HtmlPage page = webClient
                .getPage("http://e-liquid-recipes.com/recipe/2254223/RY4D%20Vanilla%20Swirl%20DL");

        System.out.println(page.getElementById("rnicper").asText());

    }
```

Comment: That's right answer. JSoup gets Static html values.

Comment: Thanks, Luc. But as far as I understand, HtmlUnit can not be used on 
 Android. And Selenium/Appium  carries too much extra functionality.

Comment: BTW, "rnstr" and "nirat" are also not static html?

Comment: you can log the result of Jsoup.connect("http://e-liquid-recipes.com/recipe/2254223/RY4D%20Vanilla%20Swirl%20DL").get(); to see how webpage downloaded by joup looks like.

Comment: There are some options to make HtmlUnit work under Android, try to look at them. You can also try to look on how this webpage is loaded and look at network communication if there is possibility to get data in other way.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following class in your Activity class and do your execution using JSoup. This code is used to get current version from play store website. you can change the URL and `div[id=rnicper]` into `select()` method. and then do your execution in `postExecute()` method.

```
private class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String newVersion = null;
        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
            return newVersion;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return newVersion;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
        super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
        if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
            if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
                showAlertDialogForUpdate(currentVersion, onlineVersion);
            }
        }
        Log.e("update", "Current version " + currentVersion + "playstore version " + onlineVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: doc.select("div[id=rnicper]").text(); return empty string

Comment: Added to my post.